# JQuery stops responding after sorting the first time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

This is my index.php which works at first when clicked for sorting

```
<html>   
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#tablesorter-demo").trigger("update");
            $("#tablesorter-demo").tablesorter({
                sortList: [
                    [0, 0],
                    [2, 1]
                ],
                widgets: ['zebra']
            });
            $("#options").tablesorter({
                sortList: [
                    [0, 0]
                ],
                headers: {
                    3: {
                        sorter: false
                    },
                    4: {
                        sorter: false
                    }
                }
            });
        });


        function showUser(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("subjtable").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("subjtable").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "getSubject.php?q=" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
    <title>Faculty Subject</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
         <h1 align="center">Faculty Subject Offerings</h1>

        <br/>
         <h1>Faculty</h1>

         <h1>
        <select name="typeselector" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
            <option value="Arts">Arts</option>
            <option value="Science">Science</option>
        </select>
    </h1>

        <div id="subjtable">
            <table id="tablesorter-demo" class="tablesorter" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Subject Code</th>
                        <th>Subject Title</th>
                        <th>Lecturer</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '9876543210', 'jye');
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select subjectcode,title,lecturer,description from erehwonsubjects");
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result($subjcode,$subjtitle,$lecturer,$description);
                while($stmt->fetch()) {
                    echo <<<TABLE
                    <tr>
                        <td>$subjcode</td>
                        <td>$subjtitle</td>
                        <td>$lecturer</td>
                        <td>$description</td>
                        </tr>
                    TABLE;
                } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

It's working when running this php and connect with my database. Mention again. working perfectly in this php

but then i change my select box value and it will send method POST to another php namegetSubject.php

```
<html>  
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#tablesorter-demo").trigger("update");
                $("#tablesorter-demo").tablesorter({
                    sortList: [
                        [0, 0],
                        [2, 1]
                    ],
                    widgets: ['zebra']
                });
                $("#options").tablesorter({
                    sortList: [
                        [0, 0]
                    ],
                    headers: {
                        3: {
                            sorter: false
                        },
                        4: {
                            sorter: false
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="subjtable">
            <table id="tablesorter-demo" class="tablesorter" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Subject Code</th>
                        <th>Subject Title</th>
                        <th>Lecturer</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php $q=$ _GET[ "q"]; $mysqli=n ew mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '9876543210', 'jye'); $stmt=$ mysqli->prepare("select subjectcode,title,lecturer,description from erehwonsubjects where course = '".$q."'"); $stmt->execute(); $stmt->bind_result($subjcode,$subjtitle,$lecturer,$description); while($stmt->fetch()) { echo
                    <<<TABLE <tr>
                        <td>$subjcode</td>
                        <td>$subjtitle</td>
                        <td>$lecturer</td>
                        <td>$description</td>
                        </tr>TABLE; } ?></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then at the second php there. my Jquery sorting already cannot work . my Jquery do is based on this website
http://tablesorter.com/docs/

any answer will be appreciate. first time user at here 
i already searched answer and here but found nothing for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your code does what you think it does.

- You activate the onchange of `<select name="typeselector" onchange="showUser(this.value)">`
- The onchange is sending a GET request using `XMLHttpRequest`
- The request is sent to `"getSubject.php?q="+str`
- The "response" you are sending back is an entire HTML webpage (`<html>...content...</html>`)
- You're then attempting to insert this response into the DIV on the first page using `document.getElementById("subjtable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;`

Essentially, you're trying to stick a webpage within another webpage.

To give you the right direction, change getSubject.php to only be the following, and test it out then:

```
       <table id="tablesorter-demo" class="tablesorter" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Subject Code</th>
                        <th>Subject Title</th>
                        <th>Lecturer</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            $q=$_GET["q"];

                    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','9876543210','jye');
                    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select subjectcode,title,lecturer,description from erehwonsubjects where course = '".$q."'");
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->bind_result($subjcode,$subjtitle,$lecturer,$description);
                    while($stmt->fetch())
                    {

                          echo <<<TABLE
                            <tr>
                                <td>$subjcode</td>
                                <td>$subjtitle</td>
                                <td>$lecturer</td>
                                <td>$description</td>
                            </tr> 

TABLE;

                    }

                    ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And note, this is not the "proper" way to handle it, but should work to give you the idea of what was wrong.

Comment: i changed but it's still not work. i get you mean that i stick with another webpage. so how i going to force it to another page or?

Comment: You also need to trigger a re-update of the tablesorter plugin, by essentially running your anonymous function again (the function containing `$("#tablesorter-demo").trigger("update");`). Do it after the `document.getElementById("subjtable").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;` This is so that the plugin recognizes that you've replaced the table and re-creates the necessary elements.

Comment: is not working also after i add that trigger after the function on my first page php.. @jacob

Comment: Is the new table showing up inside the first page after you change the select box?

Comment: my new table able to changed when i post this question. just the row cannot clickable for sorting. table can change but not clickable. first page can change and clickable

Comment: Just a note, half your javascript in the function() does not appear to be relevant, only `$("#tablesorter-demo").tablesorter({ sortList: [ [0, 0], [2, 1] ], widgets: ['zebra'] });` is relevant to recreating the table sorter on the new table (it appears).

Comment: i changed and not work also.. cna u help me have a look on this please? http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/c78-a84

just a link and see the problem wher emight cause it

Comment: Sorry @ChrisTeh -- this is as much as I can do. I would highly suggest that you spend some time learning javascript/jQuery/dom manipulation if this can't answer your question. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/yvn-9w3